# Issue generating an Angular endpoint / Model with multipart/form-data

Tags: angular, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli, contract-first

The following is an excempt from my OpenAPI specification that I use to generate my angular services with `openapi-generator-cli`:

```yaml
  requestBody:
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            test:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
                format: byte
```

This request body fails to generate with the following warning output in the generation process:

```
[main] WARN  o.o.codegen.DefaultCodegen - Could not compute datatypeWithEnum from string, null
```

I originally had a more complex structure of schemas, but I narrowed it down to this part:
an object with a property that is an array containing a byte array (putting the items of the array in an object has no impact). If I were to move the byte array property into the test object, it generates, but as soon as I have one or multiple arrays containing the byte array it does not work anymore.

I run the generator command through npm as a script:

```
"openapi-generator-cli generate -i ../../../../openapi/openapi.yaml -g typescript-angular -o src/generated-sources/openapi --additional-properties=supportsES6=true,npmVersion=6.9.0,ngVersion=14",
```

Previously I had the content type set to `application/json` and it worked fine, simply changing the content type to `multipart/form-data` made it not work anymore and I sadly am required to use `multipart/form-data` in the future.

Help or suggestions are highly appreciated

What I have tried:

- Using `binary` and or `base64` as the format
- OpenAPI generator versions 5.1.1 and 6.4.0
- turning on verbose logging (no extra lines of warning or errors are output)
- reducing my more complex datastructure to the shown example
- read through following post: [OpenAPI Example multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68847193/openapi-example-multipart-form-data) which seems to depict a very similar datastructure but it seems to work(?)
- found [OpenAPI V3 Maven Plugin generates incomplete interface code with multiple file upload using multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70295632/openapi-v3-maven-plugin-generates-incomplete-interface-code-with-multiple-file-u) which seems to describe a similar issue but with a java generator
- found and tried solution from [swagger-ui - open api 3, multipart/form-data array problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213067/swagger-ui-open-api-3-multipart-form-data-array-problem) (change name of property to include `[]` brackets) with no change in outcome